# What is Banana split and fusion in functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

These terms got mentioned in my university course. Quick googling pointed me to some university papers, but I am looking for a simple explanation.

Comment: @jozefg: Thanks for the link to your post. One question about it. In the sentence "An algebra in this sense is a pair of an object C, and a map F C → C.", is C really supposed to be an object, or rather a category? In other words, I am not sure if F denotes a functor in a category, and the F-algebras are the algebras induced by that functor, of if F is a particular arrow from an object onto itself.

Comment: `C` is an object in some category (let's say `CC`), `F` is a functor from `CC -> CC` so it maps `CC` back onto itself. Now `F CC -> CC` is just a normal arrow in the category `CC`. So an `F` algebra is an object `C : CC` and an arrow `F C -> C` in `CC`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though 2 answers have already been provided, I don't think the "banana split" has been explained here yet.

It is indeed defined in "Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire, Erik Meijer Maarten Fokkinga, Ross Paterson, 1991"; that article is hard to read (for me) due to its heavy use of Squiggol. However, "A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold, Graham Hutton, 1999" contains a definition that is easier to parse:

> As a simple first example of the use of *fold* to generate tuples, consider the function *sumlength* that calculates the *sum* and *length* of a list of numbers:
>
> ```
> sumlength :: [Int] → (Int,Int)
> sumlength xs = (sum xs, length xs)
> ```
>
> By a straightforward combination of the definitions of the functions *sum* and *length* using *fold* given earlier, the function *sumlength* can be redefined as a single application of *fold* that generates a pair of numbers from a list of numbers:
>
> ```
> sumlength = fold (λn (x, y) → (n + x, 1 + y)) (0, 0)
> ```
>
> This definition is more efficient than the original definition, because it only makes a single traversal over the argument list, rather than two separate traversals. Generalising from this example, any pair of applications of *fold* to the same list can always be combined to give a single application of *fold* that generates a pair, by appealing to the so-called ‘banana split’ property of *fold* (Meijer, 1992). The strange name of this property derives from the fact that the *fold* operator is sometimes written using brackets (| |) that resemble bananas, and the pairing operator is sometimes called split. Hence, their combination can be termed a banana split!

Answer (score 20):

So this is actually a referenced to a paper by Meijer and a few others called "[Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf)", the basic idea is that we can take any recursive data type, like say

```
 data List = Cons Int List | Nil
```

and we can factor out the recursion into a type variable

```
 data ListF a = Cons Int a | Nil
```

the reason why I appended that `F` is because this is now a functor! It also allows us to mimic lists, but with a twist: to build lists we have to nest the list type

```
type ThreeList = ListF (ListF (ListF Void)))
```

To recover our original list we need to keep nesting this *infinitely*. That will give us a type `ListFF` where

```
  ListF ListFF == ListFF
```

To do this define a "fixed point type"

```
  data Fix f = Fix {unfix :: f (Fix f)}
  type ListFF = Fix ListF
```

As an exercise, you should verify this satisfies our above equation.Now we can finally define what bananas (catamorphisms) are!

```
  type ListAlg a = ListF a -> a
```

`ListAlg`s are the type of "list algebras", and we can define a particular function

```
  cata :: ListAlg a -> ListFF -> a
  cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . unfix
```

Further more

```
  cata :: ListAlg a -> ListFF -> a
  cata :: (Either () (Int, a) -> a) -> ListFF -> a
  cata :: (() -> a) -> ((Int, a) -> a) -> ListFF -> a
  cata :: a -> (Int -> a -> a) -> ListFF -> a
  cata :: (Int -> a -> a) -> a -> [Int] -> a
```

Look familiar? `cata` is precisely the same as right folds!

What's really interesting is that we can do this over more than just lists, any type which is defined with this "fixed point of a functor" has a `cata` and to accomdate them all we just have to relax the type signature

```
  cata :: (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
```

This is actually inspired from a piece of category theory which [I wrote about](http://jozefg.bitbucket.org/posts/2014-11-19-recursion.html), but this is the meat of the Haskell side.

Comment: is it worth mentioning that the bananas are (| |) brackets that the original paper uses to define cata

Answer (score 8):

Although jozefg provided an answer, I am not sure if it answered the question. The "fusion law" is explained in the following paper:

> A tutorial on the universality and
>   expressiveness of fold, GRAHAM HUTTON, 1999

Basically it says that under some conditions you can combine ("fuse") the composition of a function and fold into a single fold, so basically

> h · fold g w = fold f v

The conditions for this equality are

> h w = v 
>   h (g x y) = f x (h y)

The "banana split" or "banana split law" is from the article

> Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses,
>   Envelopes and Barbed Wire, Erik Meijer  Maarten Fokkinga, Ross Paterson, 1991

Unfortunately the article is very hard to decipher as it uses the Bird–Meertens formalism
so I could not make head or tail of it. As far as I understood the "banana split law" it says that if you have 2 folds operating on the same argument, they can be merged into a single fold.